# WPF Sizing Grid.Row to content

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, gridpanel, sizetocontent

I have a window that uses `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and I have a column that has three rows in it.  Rows are defines as such:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Content is made up of one other Grid panel per above row.  Each of those panels contains a label and a ListBox.  ListBox dynamically adds or removes its content.  So, it might have one item, or it might have 100 items.

My problem is this:  When my application starts, the three above-mentioned rows are sized to the content within them.  So it looks pretty neat.  If the first row contains only one item in the ListBox, it'll size it just enough to fit those items.  The other two rows (if overfilled with content) will split the rest of the space in half and make their scroll bars visible if the user wants to see the overflows in each one.  However, as soon as I re-size the main window, the three rows will immediately re-size themselves to where each one will be the exact same height, no matter the amount of content in them.

I tried using `Height="Auto"` in the row definitions of the outer grid; however, that sizes each row to fit the content precisely, thus causing them to overflow off the screen, without ever enabling the scroll bars.

I've tried every setting that I know of (key: know of) and I couldn't solve it.  For now I got rid of `SizeToContent` so that that weird bug wouldn't happen, but the rows are sized proportional to each other no matter the amount of content in them... and I'd like it the other way.  I don't want a static height for each of the rows, but rather having them to re-size themselves dynamically, based on the amount of content in them without going off the screen.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it right you'll have to make your own custom `Panel` which handles size distribution smarter than the standard `Grid`. This project may be a good starting point: [ConstrainingStackPanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37163/WPF-A-Constraining-Stack-Panel)

Comment: That is a fantastic link.  That is very much like what I'm trying to accomplish.  It contains everything within the available space.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML you could bind to a property in your ViewModel

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Row1Height}"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Row2Height}"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Row3Height}"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then in your ViewModel

```
public int Row1Height { get; set; }
public int Row2Height { get; set; }
public int Row3Height { get; set; }
```

And have some calculation that populates that value once you have content.

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  A lot of work as far as the calculation goes, but I haven't found anything else that can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, have you tried wrapping it inside of a ScrollViewer and turning the scollbar off for the ListView?

I've found that layout rendering in WPF can be both a positive and a crutch.  It's sometimes a pain in the butt to get it to work right when it comes to content sizing.

If a ScrollViewer is not an approach you'd like to take, you could easily accomplish something like this through writing some sort of attached behavior (I've done this in the past) but in this case it's way overkill.

Example of ScrollViewer approach:

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Something}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
  :
  :
  :
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried this approach; however, if I add all of them to ScrollViewer, then I'll be scrolling through all three of them at the same time.  Problem with that is that if the first one has a ton of content, the other two will be somewhere off screen.  I want all three to be visible at the same time.  If each one is wrapped into ScrollViewer, then similar results as what I had previously occur.

Comment: I see...if I were you I'd probably have a look at writing an attached behavior to handle the autosizing then.  This would put the full control of sizing into your hands.

I unfortunately don't have the wherewithal to sit down and do this right now.  I do know it's doable though.